# Adobe Photoshop CS5 (12) - only partial coverage when clicking with brush or erase tools

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

For some time now I have been unable to determine why my brush or eraser tools do not completely cover the area outlined by my tool. I have reset brush settings as well as reloaded the brushes themselves. Notice in my animated gif that there is an area just inside the tool outline that is not covered when I click - even though hardness, opacity and flow are set to maximum and spacing is set to 1%. The area of the uncovered space increases proportionately as I increase the brush/eraser size.

[image: Photoshop brush/eraser incomplete coverage]

**EDIT**: Brush size is set to normal and jitter is set to 0%

Comment: Try to do ALT+CRTL+Move your mouse down (for mac).

Moving up = Add blur
Moving down = Remove blur
Moving left = smaller brush
Moving right = bigger brush

If your brush is a bit blured, it reduce the shape size. It may be the issue...

Comment: Hi @danwpc. Please don't edit answers by other people to respond to them. This is exactly why we have comments below the answers. You can also [edit] your own question to add more information

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Photoshop preferences (CTRL + K), select the tab 'cursors' and choose '*Normal brush tip*'. Yours is probably on full size brush tip (see example). [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try on Brush setting > Shape Dynamics> SizeJitter to 0%

[image: http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/basics/photoshop-brushes/brush-dynamics/shape-dynamics-options.gif]

Comment: Given that `Shape Dynamics` is not checked in his gif, that shouldn't be the issue.